# Generate Alias for MainWindow

Tags: c#, wpf, type-alias

I want to access a variable from my MainWindow in second Window my WPF application.

its a simple application so i dont use MVVM.

currently i am using this line of code

```
var x = ((MainWindow)Application.Current.MainWindow).something;
```

is there a way to make an alias for

```
((MainWindow)Application.Current.MainWindow)
```

this part?

is this even possible in C#?

i only found answers where they used the code segment above.

Comment: If it's just a variable then you could add a static class with a static public variable or property. Set that in mainwindow and any other class has access to the same instance because it's a static.

Comment: yes i already thought about that but i really dont like the aspekt of static classes nor variables

Comment: I would usually avoid statics myself. Put objects in an ioc container or as resources. In fact if this was something that's displayed then a resource which is an instance class implementing inotifypropertychanged would be another candidate.

Comment: yes, usally i impelemnt INotifyPropertyChanged but only if i use MVVM design pattern, but this application is so basic and simple its not needed here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you store this in variable.

```
var mainWindow = (MainWindow)Application.Current.MainWindow;
```

And use

```
var x = mainWindow.something;
```

Comment: thanks i used it in my class like this, `private Window mainWindow = ((MainWindow) Application.Current.MainWindow);` but i totally forgott aboit my MainWindow cast... thanks for the prompt answer dough!